# Jquery UI Photo Manager with radio button not clicking

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Ok I am still working on this jquery photo manager which you can see the full workings of the original here http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager

Here is the problem I am having I have included a radio button for each picture. I have been banging my head against the wall wondering why I could not click on and make the radio buttons change. Now I realized what is causing this and it is this part of the code 
I added this part in

```
else if ($target.is("input.ismainchk")) {
            //recycleImage($item);
        }
```

I don't really need for it to fire another function when the radio button is clicked I just need the radio button to click

Here is some of the HTML so you get an idea of what I am working with.

```
    <ul id="gallery" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-droppable">
<li id="d386f25f-66b8-429d-aaa9-c0552a4839fa" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr ui-draggable" style="width: 96px; display: list-item;">
<h5 class="ui-widget-header">
<input id="textd386f25f-66b8-429d-aaa9-c0552a4839fa.jpg" class="ghost-text" type="text" size="13" defaultval="Picture Headline" maxlength="150" style="color: grey;">
</h5>
<img id="../userimages/d386f25f-66b8-429d-aaa9-c0552a4839fa.jpg" width="96" height="72" src="../userimages/d386f25f-66b8-429d-aaa9-c0552a4839fa.jpg">
<a class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin" href="images/high_tatras4.jpg" title="View larger image">View larger</a>
<input id="d386f25f-66b8-429d-aaa9-c0552a4839fa.jpgmain" class="ismainchk" type="radio" title="Main Img" name="maingroup">
<a class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" title="Delete this image" href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off">Delete image</a>
</li>
```

Here is the part of the JQuery that is giving the problem.

```
        // resolve the icons behavior with event delegation
    $("ul.gallery > li").click(function (event) {
        var $item = $(this),
            $target = $(event.target);

        if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-trash")) {
            deleteImage($item);
        } else if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-zoomin")) {
            viewLargerImage($target);
        } else if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-refresh")) {
            recycleImage($item);
        } else if ($target.is("input.ismainchk")) {
            //recycleImage($item);
        }

        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after researching this for a few days now I found the answer after a ton of trial and error.
The return false; at the end was causing the radio buttons to not be checked. Moving the return false to the individual items that specifically needed it allowed the radio buttons to be checked

```
        $("ul.gallery > li").click(function (event) {
        var $item = $(this),
            $target = $(event.target);

        if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-trash")) {
            deleteImage($item);
            return false;
        } else if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-zoomin")) {
            viewLargerImage($target);
            return false;
        } else if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-refresh")) {
            recycleImage($item);
            return false;
        }           

    });
```